# the SUM of SQlite statement not reset everytime I restart the emulator

Tags: android, sqlite

i have the following function:

```
    public double countingDistance (KeretaDbHelper stationData, int indexStationFrom, int indexStationTo, String dbField, String stationDistance, String tableName){//KeretaDbHelper dataStasiun, String stasiunAwal, String stasiunAkhir, String tableName, String dbField, String cols1, String cols2)
    double totalDistance = 0;
    if(indexStationFrom > indexStationTo) {
        int temp = indexStationFrom;
        indexStationFrom = indexStationTo;
        indexStationTo = temp;
    }

    SQLiteDatabase stationDatabase = stationData.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor stationCur = stationDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + stationDistance + ") AS myTotal FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + dbField + " BETWEEN " + indexStationFrom + " AND " + indexStationTo, null);
    //SQLiteStatement stationCur = stationDatabase.compileStatement("SELECT SUM(" + stationDistance + ") AS myTotal FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + dbField + " BETWEEN " + indexStationFrom + " AND " + indexStationTo + "");
    if(stationCur != null && stationCur.moveToFirst())
    {
        totalDistance = stationCur.getDouble(stationCur.getColumnIndex("myTotal"));
        stationCur.close();
    }
    stationDatabase.close();
    return totalDistance;
}
```

As in the title, every time i restart the android (reopen/rerun the application) The totalDistance is not reset to 0, and keep adding the previous SUM, it is like adding the previous run with the current run.

any idea why i keep getting this???

thanks

Comment: Is the underlying on the database changing?  Doing a `SELECT` by itself should not have an effect on the persisted data.

Comment: No, if i run the query on the sqlite shell, it is fine, but the amount of sum will follow the last android run..